# lock() method in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

May be this is silly on my part but I looked at the source code for `ConcurrentHashMap` and I was not able to see the definition of the method `lock()` anywhere in that class, but I can see this method being invoked at several occasions. In Eclipse , when I say open declaration on `lock()`, it shows the class `ReentrantLock.lock()` , so I am confused how this works ? Where is the object reference of the `ReentrantLock` for the lock() method invocation ?

```
 V readValueUnderLock(HashEntry<K,V> e) {
        lock(); // where is this method defined in CHM ?
        try {
            return e.value;
        } finally {
            unlock();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That code fragment is inside an inner class within `ConcurrentHashMap` called `Segment`, which extends `ReentrantLock`

Comment: Yes , I was indeed silly not to scroll up and see the nested class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lock method in ConcurrentHashMap. Look at [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). So i don't see how you could have seen any code to this inexistent method.

`readValueUnderLock` is a method of the inner class `Segment`, which extends `ReentrantLock`. So the lock method you're seeing is the lock method of ReentrantLock.